# How to make typescript, eslint complain when violating?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, winscp

I am using typescript + eslint and I am able to make use of them but I feel like I am not using them effectively. My .ts files are in WinSCP server and every time when I write code I have to open the .ts files from WinSCP in VS Code editor. Here I don't get any complaints (*red underlines*) from typescript and also eslint when I am typing line(s) of code that actually violates the rules.

I get the errors while compiling the .ts files and also running `npx eslint <filename>`. Is there a way to make typescript and eslint complain at the moment of typing bad code?

Comment: Have a complete local copy of the project (which can be used for development, including linting, and also for testing), then move the copy over to the server at once when you're ready. Ideally this would be set up with something like git hooks, when deploying to staging, to automate things - that way you never have to touch manually moving over code (with WinSCP or anything else)

Comment: VS Code reads by default the configuration files from the root of the opened folder. If you have to open each file seperatelly with WinSCP, this means, that most probably there is no configuration for VS Code, which it could use.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  But @CertainPerformance, I cannot access the databases from my local machine, the DB can be accessed only from the WinSCP server. Considering this situation do you still prefer to take local copy write code for DB tasks then move to server, test it, and so on? Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: You could create a dummy database for local testing. I don't have all that much confidence in my knowledge here, but yes, I'd really do whatever I could to enable local coding, unless your IDE supports what's essentially a remote desktop connection, which sounds unlikely and quite a pain even if possible

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, your thoughts are really helpful.

Comment: Don't know how feasible it is, but you might be able to have an environment variable like DATABASE_URL, if the database can be interfaced (with authorization) with over the internet